# Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable. Flutter 2.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-web

I updated My flutter Version from 1.22 to 2.0. There are some errors in `Flutter Doctor`. How Could I solve this. That happen Afer Updated my Flutter Version.

I am Using Android Studion 4.1.2, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS(64 bit)

[image]

Comment: `$ export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=path/to/chrome`

Comment: you just need to install chorome.

Comment: Hi, I faced with the same problem. But it turned out that for MOBILE development it's not a problem at all - everything works well for Android and iOS. Looks like Chrome is necessary only for WEB development.

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of the terminal, copy the text instead  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1816774

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm on a Chromebook. I installed Flutter and Android Studio.  When I ran $flutter doctor -v, I got the same error message that you got.

I didn't need to export the file path to my path environment. I just needed to install Chrome so that Flutter could find it on my Chromebook.

Here was the command that worked for me:

`wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

Then I installed it using the Linux beta command (right click on the downloaded file, install using Linux beta).  It installed it to this directory:

`/usr/bin/`

(Alternatively, for the install, I could've used this command:

`sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`)

I ran flutter doctor -v and now it finds Chrome.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. I hadn't install google chrome. I think chromium also working for that.

Comment: I didn't even do much, I just installed Chrome and everything was fine.

Answer (score 61):

For Ubuntu 20.04, chromium is managed by snap.  I set the environment variable as shown below.

```sh
CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/snap/bin/chromium
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE
```

Try 'type chromium' to make sure of the location on your system.  I assume something similar will work for chrome.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 20.02 so I use chromium but I've same problem and I'm unable to fix it.
`type chromium` output is: `chromium is /usr/bin/chromium`
`echo $CHROME_EXECUTABLE` output is: `/usr/bin/chromium`
Do you know how can I fix it?
BTW, I'v the same issue with snap version (I uninstalled it)

Comment: this solution proposed here, indeed solved it for me !!!

Comment: also if you installed via apt, ou can set the path as: /user/bin/chromium-browser

Comment: `echo $CHROME_EXECUTABLE` nothing shows up, the output is empty

Comment: This works but everytime I close and reopen vscode this comes again!! what should I do

Comment: For me `type chromium` returns `chromium is /usr/bin/chromium`. So the two next commands solved the problem: 1) `CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/chromium` and 2) `export CHROME_EXECUTABLE`

Comment: @Benyamin you have to add the" export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/snap/bin/chromium " ( or whatever you path to google chrome or it's clone is ) to home/.bashrc at the end of the file. you can access it by sudo nano .bashrc from your home folder. it did work for me, and it took me ages to firuge out lmao

Answer (score 45):

For ones who use MacOS and with another chromium-based browser than Google Chrome (Brave in my case). You can set in `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`

```sh
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser"
```

After that, don't forget to `source ~/.zshrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` in the current terminal window.

```sh
flutter doctor -v
```

Now, "Chrome" will be seen as "Brave".

Comment: For Brave on windows, see CoderBlues Post below, but add C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe

Obviously also check if that is indeed your path :)

Answer (score 26):

I had the same error in Windows 10, Using VS Code even after setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE system environmental variable to the path of chrome.exe. I solved it by removing the double quotes around the path:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, and I put the Microsoft edge path instead since it's also based on Chromium.

Comment: I gave my Brave browser's .exe path and I'm happy to debug with Brave browser for my flutter web app. Thanks a lot

Comment: or run powershell as admin this `SetX CHROME_EXECUTABLE "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"`

Comment: Thanks @JuniorMayhé. This helped me to set edge in the CHROME_EXECUTABLE

Answer (score 15):

Even though you have a google chrome app in your system. It may have command like `google-chrome-stable` or `chrome` or any name to open chrome browser from terminal. Just duplicate the file with `google-chrome` name in `/usr/bin/`

Eg: I have `google-chrome-stable` as executable so my approach is like

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

*You may have bin in snap folder or some other folder depending on your installation way*

If you're not having chrome as executable from terminal then create a symbolic link. Find your chrome binary file and use this command

```
sudo ln -s $PATH/[google-chrome-bin] /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Replace `[google-chrome-bin]` with your binary file name

Comment: This was it for me (Artix, Arch Based distro). Thank you very much.

Comment: This answer works on Manjaro Linux

Answer (score 7):

you can export PATH in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` if you use Linux or MAC OS
you can found installed chrome PATH using `which`

for example

```sh
which google-chrome
# example result : /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

then add to `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` like this

```
# Chrome PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/google/chrome
```

then restart source

```
source .zshrc # change if you use .bashrc
```

running the `flutter doctor`

you will see the output like this

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    30.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers here have helped me setup Flutter on Mac with Microsoft Edge instead of Chrome.
For that, you simply run from your terminal:

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Microsoft Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Edge"
```

If you want to make this permanent, you should add the above line to the file

```
~/.zshenv or ~/.zshrc
```

Then save and restart terminal.

Answer (score 4):

For Linux users, you can add Edge Browser like this...

first, add this path in .bashrc file path

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable
```

then execute this command

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-stable"
```

Answer (score 2):

### For **Linux** user:

You may find this helpful if you are using similar setup as follows:

- Linux x64 (Arch Linux in my case)
- Particularly using Flatpak for browser

To test it on the current session, execute the following on the terminal:

- Brave browser:

---

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.brave.Browser/current/active/export/bin/com.brave.Browser
```

- Chrome browser:

---

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.google.Chrome/current/active/export/bin/com.google.Chrome
```

If it is working for you, proceed to execute the following command to append it to ~/.bashrc for your current user:

**Info:** *The following command will permanently save CHROME_EXECUTABLE variable to your future session and persists even after restart*

```
echo export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=$CHROME_EXECUTABLE | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

If you accidentally closed your current terminal session, you can restore the saved settings back with the following command: (Assuming you have had follow the steps above)

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If everything is working fine for you, you should be able to see the following when execute `flutter doctor -v`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## For MacOS Users

1. cd to /Users/<your user>
2. sudo nano ~/.zshenv
3. Add the following:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Microsoft Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Edge"
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Microsoft Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Edge"
```

4. Save the file and restart the IDE terminal
5. Run flutter doctor
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

For MacOs User (Vivaldi Browser or Brave Browser)

**This command sets your PATH variable for the current terminal window only. To permanently add CHROME_EXECUTABLE to your path**

**For Vivaldi Browser USer**

export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Vivaldi.app/Contents/MacOS/Vivaldi"

**For Chrome User**

export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser"

**To Find Path of browser**

Go to Activity monitor and Double click the browser you want a pop up will come choose **open Files and port** to see the location as seen below

[image: Location of browser to be added]

**To permanently add CHROME_EXECUTABLE to your path**

1. Open (or create) the rc file for your shell. Typing echo $SHELL in your Terminal tells you which shell you’re using. If you’re using Bash, edit $HOME/.bash_profile or $HOME/.bashrc. If you’re using Z shell, edit $HOME/.zshrc. If you’re using a different shell, the file path and filename will be different on your machine.
2. If you are using zsh  create .zshrc enter a command  **touch .zshrc** which will create a .zshrc file at your hardisk and vice versa for bash.
3. Go to your finder and press **shift + command + H** after that again hit a command **shift + command + .** you will find .zshrc file.
4. now open .zrch file and add your path  of your browser as i am using brave browser browser I will Use,

export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/Applications/Brave Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser"
[image]

5. Check the summary.
   [image]

Comment: I am using vivaldi browser.

Answer (score 1):

For Microsoft Edge users on Ubuntu or spinoffs.
You just need to give environment variable the 'path' of edge executable, for that we will see user

```
 export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/microsoft-edge-beta"
```

Right now edge on Linux is in beta, you can check /usr/bin to locate correct executable in future.
Then don't forget to reload environment variable by

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Or whatever environment you use like zshrc etc.

Run command `flutter doctor`, you must see Chrome path now.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me on Manjaro with ZSH

```
which google-chrome-stable
```

For me: `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Add the following:

```
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable"
```

Then save file and do:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was because the name of my chrome was "google chrome 2.app"
i renamed it to "google chrome.app"

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with just **chrome** instead of google-chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Garuda Linux and this worked for me

`sudo cp /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/bin/google-chrome`

Answer (score 0):

In my case
Google chrome was not installed in my MacBook Pro M1 chip.
Installing google chrome and allowing all recommended permissions resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have simple ran: **sudo snap install chromium**

After that, I ran command "flutter doctor" back again and chrome error was gone

```
:~$ flutter doctor
  Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
 [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS 5.19.0-46-                                                generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
 **[✓] Chrome - develop for the web**
 [✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
 [✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
 [✓] VS Code
 [✓] Connected device (2 available)
 [✓] Network resources
```