# VS Code does not show Chrome as device for Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-web

I install Flutter and VS Code in the following way:

```
$ sudo snap install --classic code
$ sudo snap install --classic flutter 
$ export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/chromium"
```

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Linux, locale en_AU.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at /home/debian/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (4 months ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/chromium

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Chromium 90.0.4430.212 built on Debian 11.0, running on Debian 11.0

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Unfortunately, VS code does not show me chrome as device:

[image]

What did I miss?

Comment: I needed to add `export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/chromium"` into `~/.bashrc`. Now it works.

Comment: For me Its brave. adding export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/snap/bin/brave" in  home > ~/.bashrc solved the problem

Comment: I leave link to answer that seems to be related and should solve/help here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69205440/6229867

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

Add the following line in `~/.profile` file *(or `~/.bash_profile` in some distros)* and re-login.

```bash
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/chromium"
```

### Long answer

For Flutter to be able to find a chromium-based browser other than google-chrome, you need to set `$CHROME_EXECUTABLE` environment variable to the path of that browser.

The issue is **where** you set this variable.

When running Flutter manually from a command shell, like bash, the variable needs to be set in that shell session. This can be achieved by just running the export command beforehand, or, as I had wrongly done it, by adding it to your shell's configuration file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

However, VS Code does not execute `flutter` via an interactive shell. So files like `.bashrc` do not get executed in this case. As a result, any logic you've set up there, like exporting `$CHROME_EXECUTABLE` or extending `$PATH`, is ignored.

To confirm this, you can execute `>Flutter: Run Flutter Doctor` in VS Code's Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`). The output will show that in VS Code's context, Flutter doesn't see the `$CHROME_EXECUTABLE` set:

```
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
```

The solution is to **define environment variables correctly**, rather than only for interactive shells. Ways of doing this are different between Linux distributions. In Arch Linux, what worked for me was to [put them in `~/.bash_profile`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Environment_variables#Per_user) instead of `~/.bashrc`. *Note that for changes to this file to take effect, you need to re-login into your system.* In Ubuntu, `~/.profile` might need to be used instead.

For excellent quick explanation on the differences between configuration files, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/789465/1774835) and others below it.