# Cannot set chrome excutable on manajaro 23.1.1

Tags: flutter, android-studio, manjaro

I have been developing a flutter application on manjaro using Android Studio. I have installed flutter using snap. I have installed Google chrome from AUR packages. I have exported the google-chrome-stable path as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631883/cannot-find-chrome-try-setting-chrome-executable-to-a-chrome-executable-flutte) and got everything green while running flutter doctor -v. But it only works on the same terminal window, if I open another terminal and run flutter doctor -v, it still complains about Chrome.

I have tried to do the export from android studio terminal and got the same result. In terminal when i run flutter devices it shows both linux and chrome but in devices drop down, i only get linux.

below is the out put of flutter doctor -v

flutter doctor -v

```
     1 ✘  1m 31s  
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Manjaro Linux 6.6.8-2-MANJARO, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.16.5 on channel stable at /home/megam/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 78666c8dc5 (12 days ago), 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
    • Engine revision 3f3e560236
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/megam/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/140/jbr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
    • cmake version 3.16.3
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/140
    • Flutter plugin version 77.1.2
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Manjaro Linux 6.6.8-2-MANJARO
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 120.0.6099.129

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

[image]

Manjaro Version :

```
DISTRIB_ID="ManjaroLinux"
DISTRIB_RELEASE="23.1.1"
DISTRIB_CODENAME="Vulcan"
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Manjaro Linux"
```